# MySql Date between : weird behaviour

Tags: mysql, date, between

I have a blocking problem with my mysql dabatase.

I have a php website with a MySql database.
Everything works fine.

I just put a sql dump from one old database server to a new database server and since, on this new server I have a weird behaviour:

A query like:

```
select * from toto where date(myDateField) between '2001-01-01' and '2012-01-01';
```

Does not work. What I mean is that it does not return any results (no errors either).

If I do the following :

```
select * from toto where myDateField between '2001-01-01' and '2012-01-01';
```

It works.

I tryied to see if on my new server my mysql system variables are different but all seems the same.
The weird thing is that on this new server I allready put another dump last week and everything worked juste fine.
Now I have no idea.

I cannot go and modify all my php files, since the website works fine on others servers. I just want to find the problem and the explanation.

Anyone has any hint on this?

UPDATED:

I have done more tests.
I have 2 databases on the same server.
On the first one (created a older dump) everything it's fine.
On the second one (created using a recent dump file) I have the problem.

So I don't really know what could be the problem.

Comment: What is the datatype of `myDateField` ?

Answer (score 0):

First check the which format do u get in your server

```
select date(myDateField) from toto
```

Based on the format use between condition ... the date format may change form server to server i.e dd//mm//yyyy or yy//mm/dd check that ....

Comment: I did that and is the same on both servers. I checked even in the mysql system variables: the same setting.

Comment: SELECT * FROM toto where  DATE_FORMAT(myDateField, '%Y-%m-%d')  between '2001-01-01' and '2012-01-01'; try this

Comment: With date_format it's working. So what should I change on my server ?

Comment: No need change any in server .Do u any other prob when u use DATE_FORMAT . if not just user date_format.

Comment: I don't know exacly. My whole website is acting weird. Many pages does are not displaying...What do you suspect ?

Comment: I just did the following: On this new server I put an old dump in a different database. With this one everything is ok. If I swithc back to the other database (on the same server), it does not works. So I'm thinking a problem when doing the dump ?

Comment: Is your website more depend on date and time . Then may be problem for set the time zone correctly.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work. I installed the same dump on a different linux distribution and now it works. Before I had Gentoo and now I have Ubuntu.
So it must be something wrong on Gentoo.